# Detect and Handle Pop-ups in Webview and open url in new Tab or window

Tags: android, popup, android-webview, android-browser

I just want to know is there is any other way to handle pop up for websites in android Webview and opening in new tab or open in new window using webview.

open urls which are generally opened in new window in normal browser.

I am still learning the browser implementation ,so my question can be a little naive so please bear with it :)